# Problems with Multiprocessing import Pool, using Selenium for webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I am having a problem using the Pool class of Multiprocessing library.

I have the following code that takes a list as an input, and scrapes into a soup object, which it then puts into a list and returns

```
def extract_BS(urls):

        BS_LIST = []


        for url in urls:
            try:

                browser = webdriver.Firefox()
                browser.get(url)                   
                print('Processing..' + url)

                respData = browser.page_source
                soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(respData, 'html.parser')
                BS_LIST.append(soup)
                browser.quit()

            except Exception as e:
                print(url)
                print('Exception:',e)
                pass

        return BS_LIST
```

I have used this with a list of 10 urls, and it works. Now, I want to using multithreading to improve the speed of the scraping. I use the following code, where urls = a list of 10 urls

```
with Pool(10) as p:
    records = p.map(extract_BS, urls)

p.terminate()
p.join()
```

I get an error, which in essence states that it is using the first letter of each url in urls.

```
​
h
Exception: Message: Malformed URL: h is not a valid URL.
```

For some reason it takes the first letter of the first element of my list, as opposed to the actual first entry. Any help please?

Comment: I think typically with this pattern of parallelism, the map function takes a function, then an iterable, whose only argument is each item in the iterable. Your function is both generating the list of URLs and processing them. Get the data structure separately ("urls"), then make sure your worker function only accepts one URL at a time.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!